# Create SOAP Request from JWSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, axis

Hey there, I have been working with JWSDL to allow me to programatically work with WSDL files. I now want to create SOAP requests that can be sent to the server. How do I generate these requests from the JWSDL classes? any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: What does the JWSDL documentation suggest you do?

Comment: The actual documentation doesn't mention much beyond the usage of extensions. However, I do not understand the usage of extensions for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

> Here, i have created a sample web service which takes two parameters
>   number1 and number2. And gives the response as number3 (= number1 +
>   number2). Web service is already deployed on localhost:8080 (tomcat
>   server)

**Your answer starts from here**.

> i have created a sample java file... which passes two parameters to a
>   web service in a SOAP request and gets the SOAP response from the web
>   service. You can get the parameters(described in a code) like getCalculation ,m , localhost:8080, number1, number2 and url from the WSDL file.

**Sample Code:**

```
package SampleJavaWSDLDemo;
```

- import javax.xml.soap.*;
- import java.util.*;
- import java.net.URL;
- import javax.xml.transform.*;
- import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
- import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
- import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
- import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
- import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
- import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
- import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
- import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
- import java.net.URL;

public class SampleJavaWSDLDemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try {

    //Create a SOAPMessage
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection connection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
    MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();
    SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPHeader();
    SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
    header.detachNode();

    Name bodyName = soapFactory.createName("getCalculation", "m", "http://localhost:8080/");
    SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);

            //Insert Content
    Name name = envelope.createName("number1");
    SOAPElement symbol = bodyElement.addChildElement(name);
    symbol.addTextNode("10");
    name = envelope.createName("number2");
    symbol = bodyElement.addChildElement(name);
    symbol.addTextNode("20");

            System.out.println("\n Request: \n");
            message.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println();

            // Create an endpint point which is either URL or String type
    URL endpoint = new URL("http://localhost:8080/WebServiceName/OperationName");

            //Send a SOAPMessage (request) and then wait for SOAPMessage (response)
    SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, endpoint);

    // Get the response from the webservice.                
    SOAPBody soapBody = response.getSOAPBody();

    System.out.println("\n Response: \n");
    TransformerFactory transformerfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerfactory.newTransformer();
    Source sourceContent = response.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
    System.out.println();
    String resp = response.getSOAPBody().getElementsByTagName("return").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
    System.out.println("Answer is: " + resp);

    connection.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Try to run this code.
It can give you a whole soap request and response message.