# How to parse wsdl and xsd files?

Tags: java, web-services, parsing, xsd, wsdl

I've been looking for a way to programmatically parse WSDL and associated XSD files to get values from annotation / documentation tags. I managed to get  values from wsdl using wsdl4j, but how do i do this for XSD files? I tried to use XSOM but for some reason i always get null.

Comment: Two questions in one. For XSD, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996857/java-api-to-parse-xsd-schema-file

Answer (score 1):

**1).** Hope this link will be useful for you to choose the best parser, [`Parse WSDL Effectively`](http://oracled.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/parse-wsdl-effectively/).

I have tried using [`Apache Woden`](http://ws.apache.org/woden/), [`WSDL4J`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j/) and [`Membrane SOA`](http://www.membrane-soa.org/). Among these, Membrane SOA seems to be developer friendly.

**2).** Place the dependent XSD's in the folder where you have placed the WSDL. Then try parsing your WSDL, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the JWSDL help will be of service. It also makes calls to the services.

[Here a discussion on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560755/create-soap-request-from-jwsdl)