# Parsing wsdl and xsd

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl, xsom

I've been looking for a way to programmatically parse WSDL and associated XSD files to get values from annotation / documentation tags. I managed to get values from wsdl using wsdl4j, but how do i do this for XSD files? I tried to use XSOM but for some reason i always get null.

Comment: Try using SAX Parser or post your code here so that someone can help you.

Comment: exact duplicate! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632026/how-to-parse-wsdl-and-xsd-files

Answer (score 0):

You can attack the files with any XML parser (or jdom, dom4j, etc.). Simply select all documentation and annotations nodes to get the text (using XPath expressions) and inspect the parent nodes to see, what's documented or annotated.